# Angular component communication - using ngIf with booleans from a service

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, observable

I have 2 sibling components and I am showing an API result if there is a successful response and an API Failure error message if there is an API error. If there is an API Failure in both components, I need to show only 1 API Failure error message. I have managed to do this and I used a service to define booleans and use them in the components. However, I am wondering if there is a better solution like using Input, Output, EventEmitter or Subject.

message.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isTodosLoaded && !appService.isAPIError">{{ todos.title }}</div>
<div *ngIf="!isTodosLoaded && appService.isAPIError">{{ appService.APIErrorMessage }}</div>
```

message2.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isTodos2Loaded && !appService.isAPI2Error">{{ todos2.title }}</div>
<div *ngIf="!isTodos2Loaded && appService.isAPI2Error && !appService.isAPIError">{{ appService.APIErrorMessage }}</div>
```

message.component.ts

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  isTodosLoaded = false;
  todos;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
  private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageService.getData()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.todos = response;
          this.isTodosLoaded = true;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.appService.isAPIError = true;
        }
      )
  }
}
```

message.component.ts

```
export class Message2Component implements OnInit {
  isTodos2Loaded = false;
  todos2;

  constructor(private message2Service: Message2Service,
  private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message2Service.getData()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.todos2 = response;
          this.isTodos2Loaded = true;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.appService.isAPI2Error = true;
        }
      )
  }
}
```

app.service.ts

```
export class AppService {
  public isAPIError = false;
  public isAPI2Error = false;
  public APIErrorMessage = "API Failure"

  constructor() { }
}
```

Source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwwicc

Comment: It doesn't look like there is much different in how these services behave. Can't you replace this with a single service which you can call twice with the appropriate arguments?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a bigger project. We have a service in each component and they have other definitions.

Comment: Take a look at a library I wrote for managing exactly this kind of scenario, ngx-rxcache https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to achieve that:

- fetch the data in the parent and send it to the child with Input.
- fetch the data somewhere in the app and save it in a service (in a Subject or in a variable) and get the data in your child from the service.
- use [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) for shared state between component.

second example:

in the parent:

```
fetch(...).subscribe(result => this.myService.setResult(result))
```

in your service:

```
result = new BehaviorSubject(null)

setResult(result):void{
  this.result.next(result);
}
```

And in your child component:

```
this.myService.result.subscribe(result => {...})
```